# Regex to extract Date in python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the date in the following format:

```
data = """*Date:* May 31, 2018 at 1:49:05 PM EDT"""
```

I need to extract the date and month in 2 different variables:

```
date = 31
month = "May"
```

How can i do that using regex in python 3??. I tried using the below regex to get the date and month:

```
month , date = re.findall("^*Date:* (\w+) (\d+)", message_data, re.MULTILINE).groups()
```

Can anyone help with this regex?

Comment: `(\w+)\s(\d{1,2}),` month is in group 1, day in group 2

Comment: See http://rextester.com/KJBKZ94704

Comment: Another option, without regex is to parse with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime): `dt = time.strptime(data, "*Date:* %B %d, %Y at %I:%M:%S %p EDT")`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex, you can just do the below code

```
data = """*Date:* May 31, 2018 at 1:49:05 PM EDT"""
month = data.split('*')[-1].split()[0]
date = data.split('*')[-1].split()[1]
print(month)
print(date.replace(',',''))
```

Output:

```
May
31
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming month is always three letters (Jan, Feb...Dec), and day is always two digist (01,02...31)

```
data = """*Date:* May 31, 2018 at 1:49:05 PM EDT"""
regexp = re.search('\*Date:\* (\w{3}) (\d{2})', data)
month, day = regexp.groups()
```

Or make it a one liner...

```
month, day = re.search('\*Date:\* (\w{3}) (\d{2})', data).groups()
```

Comment: This is the most accurate solution i was looking for... thank you very much for the solution !!!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question about using regular expressions: the issue is that you're trying to match groups, but `findall` returns a list of overall matches.  It's probably better to use `re.search`, and access the groups, as one commenter said.  Also don't forget to escape the `*` in your regular expression.  Here's a working example using `re.search`:

```
import re
data = """*Date:* May 31, 2018 at 1:49:05 PM EDT"""
result = re.search(r'^\*Date:\* (\w+) (\d+)', data)
month = result.group(1)
date = result.group(2)
print(month, date)
```

This outputs `May 31`

Comment: I think OP needs `result.group(1)` and `result.group(2)`

Comment: Ah, you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. Changed the answer.